# How can I dynamically change the offset of a Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, position, dropdown, bootstrap-5, popper.js

My web app includes dynamically built Bootstrap 5 dropdown menus that can be quite large. They need to be resized and repositioned to make the best use of screen space. So I'd like to be able to control or adjust the **offset computed by Popper.js** via javascript. But I haven't been make this work. The Popper.js documentation is not so clear, and I haven't found any documentation or examples of how to do this within Bootstrap 5. (The `data-bs-offset` attribute isn't suitable since it cannot invoke a function to provide dynamic offset values.)

Please see the code example on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Martin_ATS/cqw5mjLv/3/. I am able to access the Dropdown object both via `bootstrap.Dropdown.getInstance()` and via jQuery `$(ddelem).dropdown()`, as demonstrated in the `hideDropdown()` function. But I have not been able to change the offset via javascript despite a number of attempts at calling `setOptions()` etc.

I'd like to use Bootstrap/Popper's computed `y` offset, but adjust the `x` offset so that the menu opens closer to the left margin, and ideally leaves a right margin instead of hitting the right side of the window. The code snippet is a simplified example. In the real app, the dropdown menu contents can range from small (for which Bootstrap/Popper's normal offsets work fine) to very large (including horizontal or vertical scrolling).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the instance of the Popper (which is _popper in the dd instance), and then set the offset inside the modifers array...

```
        var dd = bootstrap.Dropdown.getInstance(evt.relatedTarget);
        console.log(`shown.bs.dropdown ${evt.relatedTarget.id}`);

        var $ddelem = $(evt.relatedTarget);
        dd._popper.setOptions( {modifiers: [
             {
                 name: 'offset',
                 options: {
                   // calculate and set the offset as needed here..
                   offset: [30, 10],
                 },
             },
        ]})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/kbCqFh5OY9)

Comment: This indeed works, thanks! Good to have this working example. BUT it seems that Popper.js's documentation is incorrect, or there's a Popper bug. It states that "we can use a function to read the current options and return updated ones" (https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/constructors/#setoptions), but when I try a `setOptions()` function, it's never called. See my updated Fiddle which uses both your method and attempts a function call: https://jsfiddle.net/Martin_ATS/jb2q3ksf/17/  That's the rabbit hole I got lost in!

Comment: Ah... Popper.js just added the `setOptions()` function argument capability on Sept. 2 (v.2.10.0). Bootstrap 5.0.x uses an earlier version of Popper.js.

Comment: sad i cant do this in bootstrap 4